# JaversException PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND: Property in derived class not found in abstract class

Tags: javers

I have a model looking something like this:

```
@Data
public abstract class InputFormGroup
{
    String id;
    String name;
    String text;
    String type;
}

@Data
public class SimpleInputFormGroup extends InputFormGroup
{
    InputControl inputControl;
    InputFormAnswerRow answerRow;
}

@Data
public class InputFormPage
{
    String id;
    String name;
    String title;
    List<InputFormGroup> inputFormGroups = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

In effect I have a larger structure that in it has InputFormPages that has one or more InputFormGroups that can be of type SimpleInputFormGroup (and also other types that I have not included in this example).

Im using MongoRepository to persist them and everything looks very nice and I can query the changes on the Entity object and it all looks good. 
The only time I have an issue is when I try to query with a path. In this example "..../inputFormPages/0/inputFormGroups/0/answerRow/answers/0".

Then I get the exception because the framework finds a list of InputFormGroup but then when it looks for answerRow in the abstract InputFormGroup base class it does naturally not find it. Is there some way to configure the model so the framework also looks in the derived classes for, in this case, the answerRow parameter? Of is it as simple as the framework doesn't support polymorphism in this way?

The error I got:

"JaversException PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND: Property 'answerRow' not found in class 'com.replior.ebrmockupbackend.model.InputFormGroup'. If the name is correct - check annotations. Properties with @DiffIgnore or @Transient are not visible for JaVers."

And the Query:

```
JqlQuery query = QueryBuilder.byValueObjectId(batch1.getId(),Batch.class,"inputForm/inputFormSteps/2/inputFormPages/0/inputFormGroups/0/answerRow/answers/0").withChangedProperty("value").build();

List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(query);
```

And the version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
    <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Appreciate any help I can get.

Link to project that exemplifies the issue:
[Github project](https://github.com/indiana-jonas/javers-inheritance-issue-example.git)

Comment: Interesting question Jonas, could you prepare a full, runnable test case with this issue? You can push it to your fork of https://github.com/javers/javers repository.

Comment: @BartekWalacik Hey thanks! I have updated my question with a little github project.  Cheers

Comment: Ok, I will check it in the next week

Comment: I have simplified you reproduction scenario to the javers test case. It's pushed here https://github.com/javers/javers/pull/700/files

Comment: It looks like a bug or missing feature, obviously, JaVers shouldn't break in that way. I will try to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in JaVers 3.11.3

Comment: Great stuff, much appreciated!